# Ignore model property when binding with ASP.NET Core Options service

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, configuration, appsettings, asp.net-core-5.0

I'm using the Options service to bind hierarchical [configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-5.0#bind-hierarchical-configuration) data.

But suppose I have a class like this:

```cs
public class PersonOptions
{

  public string Name { get; set; }

  public int Age { get; set; }

  public bool Foo {               // <--- I want binder to ignore this
    get {
      // ... do stuff
    }
  }

  public bool IgnoreMe =>         // <--- I want binder to ignore this
    throw new Exception();

}
```

Because the `Foo` property is `public`, the binder runs it and triggers some code that throws exceptions.

My design requires it to be `public`, and I prefer not to change it to a method.

Is there some attribute or override I can use to tell the binder to ignore that property?

Comment: `the binder runs it and triggers some code that throws exceptions` please share the error mesage also.

Comment: My understanding is that, technically, in the code as you have shown it, neither `Foo` nor `IgnoreMe` will be bound. `Foo` because it doesn't have both a getter and a setter; and `IgnoreMe` because it's a method.

Comment: @Auspex Yes but as I've noted, it's not that those properties are bound, it's that the binder *runs them*. See my answer below, it looks like a bug, they've added this to the backlog.

Comment: If it's a feature request, they're not treating it as a bug, but my point is that you appear to have not included all the details of your actual Property `Foo`. The documentation you cite says "read-write" properties: and Foo as you have defined it is not read-write. So, if Foo doesn't have a setter, yes, there's a bug. And `IgnoreMe` doesn't seem to even be relevant to the question.

Comment: @Auspex I addressed those points. There are no setters for those properties are they are both run. It is a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs [state](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-5.0#bind-hierarchical-configuration):

> All public read-write properties of the type are bound

If the property is public, then for some reason the binder *runs it*. Also, `[JsonIgnore]` isn't respected.

So unless I'm missing something obvious, this cannot be done.

The workarounds are:

- use a non-public property
- use a method instead of a property

I've added a feature request to the [repo](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/58384) to support an "ignore" attribute.

UPDATE:
They've added the feature request to the backlog, so I assume what I wanted cannot be done, currently.